# Enviar Socket Android A Un Servidor de Python

Tags: java, android, python

**Aclaración:**

- Los 2 dispositivos se conectan en la misma red local
- Las direcciones IP estan correctas
- Ya intente utilizando diferentes puertos
- Los permisos de la aplicacion android estan agregados correctamente
- Tambien intentado utilizando diferentes codigos encontrado en diferentes web pero nada me a funcionado
- En las imagenes se muestra que fueron ejecutadas en emulador tambien se realizaron pruebas en dispositivos reales
- Esta pregunta es realizada por no encontrar una solución en todas las demas preguntas de Stackoverflow.

**Mi Intencion:** Yo intento de que mi telefono movil pueda enviar mensajes a la computadora mediante socket

**Imagen:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La App android:** Es solo un boton que al ser presionado envia un socket y este es todo el codigo que utilizado

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.94",60);
DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
DOS.writeUTF("HELLO_WORLD");
socket.close();
```

**Python Server:** Es el servidor que recibe los mensajes

```
import socket  

s = socket.socket()   
s.bind(("192.168.1.94", 60))  
s.listen(1)  #clients permitted connect
print "server run"

sc, addr = s.accept()  

while True:  
      recibido = sc.recv(1024)  
      if recibido == "quit":  
         break        
      print "received:", recibido  
      sc.send(recibido)  

print "bye"  

sc.close()  
s.close()
```

**Mensaje De Error:**

```
2019-12-27 17:30:03.362 9255-9281/com.example.milchycompany.myapplication E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
2019-12-27 17:30:03.362 9255-9281/com.example.milchycompany.myapplication E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
2019-12-27 17:30:41.054 9255-9255/com.example.milchycompany.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.milchycompany.myapplication, PID: 9255
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:535)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:427)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:210)
        at com.example.milchycompany.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

No funciona la aplicacion de android se cierra ... una mano por favor muy agredecido

Comment: Podrias mostrar lo que obtienes en el logcat....

Comment: voy a intentar obtenerlo ya que la aplicacion se cierra y no muestra ningun mensaje de error

Comment: Me parece que no has usado adb ni logcat, te recomiendo investigar ya que te servira para depurar tus aplicaciones.

Comment: Ya agregue el logcat y los mensajes de error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sucede porque se está realizando una operación de red de E/S en el hilo principal, se debe ejecutar operaciones de red en un hilo secundario.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try  {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.94",60);
            DataOutputStream DOS = new 
            DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            DOS.writeUTF("HELLO_WORLD");
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

thread.start();
```