# El Servidor Python no recibe los datos enviado por el cliente

Tags: java, android, python

> El servidor no recibe ningun dato del cliente

Yo no puedo mostrar un mensaje de error porque no obtengo ningún mensaje de error al momento de la ejecución

**Java Cliente(Android)**

```
   try {
    Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);

    DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    DOS.writeUTF("Hola mundo enviado desde mi televisor");
    socket.close();
}

catch (Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Excepcion " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

**Python Servidor(Computador)**

```
import socket  

s = socket.socket()   
s.bind(("192.168.1.94", 60))  
s.listen(1)  #clients permitted connect
print "server run"

sc, addr = s.accept()  

while True:  
      recibido = sc.recv(1024)  
      if recibido == "quit":  
         break        
      print "received:", recibido  
      sc.send(recibido)  

print "bye"  

sc.close()  
s.close()
```

**Se ejecuta normal sin mostrar fallos**

Edicion: Quieren cerrar la pregunta porque dicen que es la misma que
 [Enviar Socket Android A Un Servidor de Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/318492/enviar-socket-android-a-un-servidor-de-python) en esa pregunta el error es `NetworkOnMainThreadException`  y esta pregunta es porque todo depura sin mostrar excepciones lo que esta sucediendo es que el servidor Python no esta recibiendo ningun dato enviado por el cliente

Comment: @eyllanesc es una pregunta totalmente diferente

Comment: @Riaven recien con tu aclaración se entiende claramente tu problema, en el caso inicial tu pregunta anterior y la actual no se diferenciaba ya que ambas indicaban: *tengo este codigo y no funciona*, te recomiendo detallar tu pregunta cuando recien los escribas y no esperes que la comunidad lo adivine. :-)

Comment: No es mi pregunta, pero buena acotación :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto resolvio mi problema, paso que se estaban realizando dos hilos al mismo tiempo por defecto solo esta permitido un hilo al mismo tiempo si vas realizar una multitarea se debe cambiar la configuracion para permitir la ejecucion de mas hilos al mismo tiempo

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                enviar.run();
    }
```

Agregando estas 2 lineas de codigo donde se ejecuta el hilo principal se soluciona

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

**StrictMode:** Es una herramienta para desarrolladores que detecta las cosas que puede estar haciendo por accidente y las señala a su atención para que pueda solucionarlas.